# SOLVED:async websockets while loop logic

Tags: python, loops, websocket, async-await

New to python. I'm trying to make something work and I don't know if my logic is legit.

So I have a weksocket (ws), for this websocket to stay connected it requires each minute, when it receives a "ping", I should reply with "pong:

So I made something like this:

```
async def run():
    prepare_env("test")
    async with websockets.connect(wss_request_url, ssl=True) as ws:
        while True:
            msg = await ws.recv()
            if msg == "ping":
                print("received: ping")
                await send(ws, "pong")
            else:
                response = json.loads(msg)
                if "something" in response:
                     await handle_message(ws, response)
                else:
                     print(f"received:{response}")
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```

Based on "something" in the response I have at some point a function (verify_price) that needs to verify in a rest API when a price changes.

```
async def verify_price(ws, old_price):
    price_changed = False
    while price_changed is False:
        price = get_new_price()
        if price <> old_price:
            await send(ws, "pricechanged")
            price_changed = True
```

My problem is that while I'm inside this while loop, waiting for the price to change, if I receive another ping, it won't reply with pong and it drops my connection.

Ty,
Danny

Comment: *"while I'm inside this loop, if I receive another ping, it won't reply with pong"* - You need to run the price checking loop on its own thread. The main thread needs to be responsible for listening to the socket and dispatching tasks to worker threads.

Comment: Even "replying with a pong" should be another thread's task. Your main loop should only stash work orders to the end of a queue and get back to listening as fast as possible, while a pool of worker threads keeps picking work orders from the front of the queue and do them.

Comment: ...and since you can't have unlimited threads, but waiting for a price change can take unlimited time, making a "while price has not changed" loop will lead to a DOS opportunity. If you have 10 workers and 10 "check price" requests come in, then your service won't respond anymore, because all 10 worker threads will be in a busy loop, waiting. Therefore, price checks should be single tasks on the main work queue. If the price has not changed, the worker thread must place another "check price" task at the end of the queue instead of going into a loop itself.

Comment: ...and (final remark) since 10 incoming price check requests could all be for the same item, and you don't want to send your worker threads into a frenzy all checking the same item in parallel, you need a registry of what you are working on, so that duplicate requests don't lead to duplicate checking, only to duplicate responses (i.e.: *"Client A, B, and C have requested X. Let's do X once, and once X is done, notify A, B, and C."*)

Comment: got it! made some threads for price checking. I guess I will improve the logic with time and experience.

Comment: Instead of changing the question to "SOLVED", if you don't expect an answer anymore, you may as well delete the question

Comment: @user2260630 Alternatively, you may share the code you have written to solve your problem in an answer of your own. Answering your own question is encouraged on Stack Overflow, you might help someone else learn this way.